# How make android application auto updateable without using google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

### how can i make my application auto updatable ? pls help.

> process that should not want user confirmation.it should be run after login automatically

`

```
 
    new Thread()
                      {
                          @SuppressWarnings({ "null", "deprecation" })
                        @Override
                         public void run() {
```

Looper.prepare();
                          Handler refresh1 = new     Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
 refresh1.post(new Runnable() {
                                          public void run()
{
//i want do here background process that search applications new version and     install it automatically.
}
}
}
}//ends thread

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices. Apps cannot install other apps, including updates to their own app, without user involvement.

Comment: Can we do this task  after user confirmation ?

Comment: @BapusahebChitale: I do not know what "this task" is. The user confirmation is at the point of installing the APK. You are welcome to download an APK from your own Web server. At the point in time when you go to install it (e.g., [via `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)), an activity will appear that the user will have to click through.

Comment: Thanks, then how can we do this ?

Comment: @BapusahebChitale: I do not know what "this" is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that... all you can do is use the Android Market API (not official) to alert the users with a new update: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Also, if you're using some webservice, you can make a validator with it... but not a single chance to auto update an app without user confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You could force users to upgrade by other means. Have your app check a URL on startup, perhaps an XML file on your website. The XML file contains the android:versionCode of the latest app release. The app then compares the retrieved version code value with its own version code, and if an upgrade is required, you can then have the app display a message "Upgrade required" or something similar, and you can either have it be a reminder message that pops up on startup (using a Toast, maybe) every time the app is run, or you can have the app refuse to function until it is upgraded.

Please note, implementing this type of behavior in your apps may violate app store policies, especially for paid apps.